# JSON eval solution for YShout

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I have [YShout](http://yurivish.com/yshout/) running for some time but after I moved to a new server with nginx and PHP5.5 it doesn't work anymore.
Firebug always returns SyntaxError: syntax error
http://domain.tld/yshout/cp/js/admincp.js
Line 295
(

This are the lines (var json is line 295):

```
json: function(parse) {
    var json = eval('(' + parse + ')');
    return json;
},
```

How can I solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You should call `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: It sounds like your server is not returning valid JSON.  Look in the network tab.

Comment: What string are you passing in? The syntax error likely comes from the `eval`ed string, not from this snippet.

Comment: The network tab doesn't show anything related as far as I can see. A fresh installed version is hosted on http://peleke.de/testfragen/yshout/test/cp/ and nothing happens with the default password fortytwo

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is configured wrong. It sends back the PHP source code, instead of interpreting it. Your ajax-loaded response currently has a value of

```
<?

class FileStorage {

    function FileStorage($path, $shoutLog = false) {
…
}

?>
```

When that gets fed into your `json` function, the `eval` throws an error like `Unhandled Error: at index 1: expected expression, got '<'`. So:

- fix your PHP
- use `JSON.parse`; [do not use `eval('(' + parse + ')')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499036/using-javascript-eval-to-parse-json).

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is related to PHP5.5!? I don't know how to fix it but I will contact the developer.