# JSON.parse causes runtime error in IE8

Tags: json, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm having problem getting '0x800a03ea - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error' when showing Google.map in IE8 (and earlier). Everything works fine in other browsers and IE9 and above. Although I've read a lot about problems with Google.map API and IE8, I don't think the problem is Google's API. When debugging, this is where the error erupts:

```
var rawObj = JSON.parse(serializedObject, MapObjectJSONParser);
```

Where the content of serializedObject is:

```
{"IsReadOnly":true,"Mode":1,"ForeignId":20,"Name":"Rådhuspladsen","Roadname":"Akseltorv","HouseNo":"1","ZipCode":"6000","City":"Kolding","Coordinates":["9.47321891784668;55.4903831481934"]} 
{"IsReadOnly":true,"Mode":1,"ForeignId":22,"Name":"Rådhustorvet","Roadname":"Rådhustorvet","ZipCode":"6400","City":"Sønderborg","Coordinates":["9.78874397277832;54.908821105957"]} 
{"IsReadOnly":true,"Mode":2,"ForeignId":12,"Name":"Amager fælled","ZipCode":"2300","City":"Amager Vest","Length":1247.88348835266,"Coordinates":["12.5822639465332;55.6549301147461","12.5779724121094;55.6439819335938"]}
```

And where MapObjectJSONParser references the following function:

```
function MapObjectJSONParser(key, value)
{
    if (key === 'Coordinates')
    {
        var coordinates = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        {
            coorItems = value[i].split(";");
            coordinates.push(MapCoordinate.Create(parseFloat(coorItems[0]), parseFloat(coorItems[1])));
        }
        return coordinates;
    }
    return value;
};
```

Anybody got any idea??

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288962/ie8-native-json-parse-bug-causes-stack-overflow

Comment: I tried to downgrade my IE10 to IE8, but when trying to apply the KB976662 update I get the message: "The update is not applicable to your computer". Then I tried to get one of my colleagues (not a developer) who gets the error in their browser to install the update. But the person got "This update is already installed on this computer". So I assume the update do not fix this error.